Nextflow Tower using Azure Batch and pre-built pools on private network is failing
I have an azure batch environment with manual pools. The pools are connected to a subnet, which includes a NAT and public IP.  The Batch network profile is configured to allow the IP's returned by https://meta.seqera.io/ , ie: "18.135.7.45/32", "18.169.21.18/32",  "18.171.4.252/32", "35.176.121.51", "35.178.254.247" + my local IP. This configuration works well when invoke from my  (desktop). Nodes can fetch data via public https and write to an internal CosmosDB.
When I try to run this same configuration in Tower (https://cloud.seqera.io/) I get failures with the following:
 Sep-25 05:07:47.678 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - >
 Awaiting termination  Sep-25 05:07:47.678 [main] DEBUG
 nextflow.Session - Session await Sep-25 05:07:47.946 [Actor Thread 2]
 DEBUG nextflow.util.CacheHelper - Hash asset file sha-256:
 /.nextflow/assets/CDCgov/nf-core-pass/bin/nf.create_entry.py Sep-25
 05:07:48.023 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.c.azure.batch.AzBatchTaskHandler
 - [AZURE BATCH] Submitting task NFCORE_PASS:PASS:create_entry (SRR9686066) -
 work-dir=az://scratch/scratch/1BeU09LmRT8FLH/52/97c023dcec06233c26f512e774de58 Sep-25 05:07:48.105 [Task submitter] DEBUG
 n.cloud.azure.batch.AzBatchService - [AZURE BATCH] Checking VM pool
 id=standard_d4_v3; size=AzVmType(name:Standard_D4_v3,
 maxDataDiskCount:8, memory:16 GB, numberOfCores:4, osDiskSize:1023 GB,
 resourceDiskSize:100 GB) Sep-25 05:07:48.111 [Task submitter] DEBUG
 n.cloud.azure.batch.AzBatchService - [AZURE BATCH] Executor
 options=endpoint=https://nextflowc51d56ffeastus.eastus.batch.azure.com;
 account-name=nextflowc51d56ffeastus; account-key=(null) Sep-25
 05:07:48.111 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.cloud.azure.batch.AzBatchService
 - [AZURE BATCH] Creating Azure Batch client using Service Principal credentials Sep-25 05:07:48.387 [pool-5-thread-1] INFO 
 c.m.a.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority - [Correlation ID:
 fe14708e-7e91-4669-8898-978551f2ef66] Instance discovery was
 successful Sep-25 05:07:48.752 [Task submitter] DEBUG
 nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Handling unexpected condition for  
 task: name=NFCORE_PASS:PASS:create_entry (SRR9686066);
 work-dir=az://scratch/scratch/1BeU09LmRT8FLH/52/97c023dcec06233c26f512e774de58   error [com.microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.BatchErrorException]:
 Status code 403, {  
 "odata.metadata":"https://nextflowc51d56ffeastus.eastus.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"AuthorizationFailure","message":{
     "lang":"en-US","value":"This request is not authorized to perform this
 operation.\nRequestId:1618957d-48a3-474e-a5f7-14e157c6a813\nTime:2024-09-25T05:07:48.6957310Z"
 } } Sep-25 05:07:48.760 [Task submitter] ERROR
 nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Error executing process >
 'NFCORE_PASS:PASS:create_entry (SRR9686066)'
 
 Caused by:   Status code 403, {  
 "odata.metadata":"https://nextflowc51d56ffeastus.eastus.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"AuthorizationFailure","message":{
     "lang":"en-US","value":"This request is not authorized to perform this
 operation.\nRequestId:1618957d-48a3-474e-a5f7-14e157c6a813\nTime:2024-09-25T05:07:48.6957310Z"
 } }
 
 com.microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.BatchErrorException: Status
 code 403, {  
 "odata.metadata":"https://nextflowc51d56ffeastus.eastus.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"AuthorizationFailure","message":{
     "lang":"en-US","value":"This request is not authorized to perform this
 operation.\nRequestId:1618957d-48a3-474e-a5f7-14e157c6a813\nTime:2024-09-25T05:07:48.6957310Z"
 } }    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at
 com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122)

**This VPN/NAT/Public IP network configuration works perfectly when invoked from my desktop.**
**If I change Batch to public access, the workflow runs using Tower.** 


Is Tower using more than the 5 IP's listed in meta.seqera.io ? ("18.135.7.45/32", "18.169.21.18/32",  "18.171.4.252/32", "35.176.121.51", "35.178.254.247") ?
Has anybody done this successfully.

